# eslint-config-airbnb on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm running into some issues when trying to install eslint-config-airbnb on Ubuntu 16.04

```
$ npm install eslint-config-airbnb
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.1.2
```

I tried installing fsevents, and that produces this error:

```
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.1.2
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

Is eslint-config-airbnb supported on linux?

Comment: [`fsevents` is an OS X-only package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents). It says in your install log that it's optional and that it was skipped. `eslint-config-airbnb` will work on Linux. I get the same errors on Windows and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this->

```
rm -rf node_modules/ && npm install && npm rebuild
```

*EDIT:* `rm -rf node_modules/` recursively removes stuff from `node_modules` folder. `npm install` will install all the package again and `npm rebuild` tries to rebuild your project.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 0):

I installed it globally, and for some reason, that worked.